# How can I update 2 tables while doing inner join MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I am trying to update 2 different table in MySql while I have them both inner joined to each other.

Here is my last try which returns the following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ticketing_system_issues AS i INNER JOIN ( SELECT d.notes, d.issue' at line 8

UPDATE i, dis
SET i.category_id = 5,
i.priority = 1,
i.issue_title = "This is a test",
dis.notes = "This is a notes test",
i.modified_on = NOW(),
i.modified_by = 2
FROM ticketing_system_issues AS i
INNER JOIN (
SELECT d.notes, d.issue_id FROM ticketing_system_discussions AS d
INNER JOIN (
SELECT issue_id, MIN(created_on) AS min_time FROM ticketing_system_discussions
GROUP BY issue_id
) AS sub ON sub.issue_id = d.issue_id AND d.created_on = sub.min_time

) AS dis ON i.issue_id = dis.issue_id
WHERE i.issue_id = 58
```

For more testing the following query to look up the field that I like to update works

```
SELECT i.category_id, i.priority, i.issue_title, dis.notes, i.modified_on, i.modified_by
FROM ticketing_system_issues AS i
INNER JOIN (
SELECT d.notes, d.issue_id FROM ticketing_system_discussions AS d
INNER JOIN (
SELECT issue_id, MIN(created_on) AS min_time FROM ticketing_system_discussions
GROUP BY issue_id
) AS sub ON sub.issue_id = d.issue_id AND d.created_on = sub.min_time

) AS dis ON i.issue_id = dis.issue_id
WHERE i.issue_id = 58
```

Comment: You can't do an `UPDATE` into the result of a subquery, you can only update real tables.

Comment: I think you need to take a step back here. You don't use `FROM` syntax with UPDATE at all.  you also can't do the update in association with grouping/aggregate functions like you are trying to do, or updates with subqueries in the JOIN conditions.  Can you explain the specific tables you are trying to update and how they are related? Can you also explain if you are actually trying to update to group s of records at once. (i.e. explain in real-world terms what you are trying to do).?

Comment: Thanks Guy, Barmar did a great job explaining the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general syntax of what you want is:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON <join condition>
SET t1.col1 = val1, t1.col2 = val2, t2.col3 = val3
WHERE <filter condition>
```

You have your `SET` clause in the wrong place.

It's not possible to do the specific `UPDATE` in your question, because you're trying to assign to a subquery, not a table. You have to separate it into a table that you assign to, and a subquery that you join with:

```
UPDATE ticketing_system_issues AS i
INNER JOIN ticketing_system_discussions AS dis ON i.issue_id = dis.issue_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT issue_id, MIN(created_on) AS min_time
            FROM ticketing_system_discussions
            GROUP BY issue_id) AS sub
      ON sub.issue_id = dis.issue_id AND dis.created_on = sub.min_time
SET i.category_id = 5,
    i.priority = 1,
    i.issue_title = "This is a test",
    dis.notes = "This is a notes test",
    i.modified_on = NOW(),
    i.modified_by = 2
WHERE i.issue_id = 58
```